# I installed pandas but while importing it I'm getting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This the error that I'm getting while importing pandas in IDLE(Python 3.8 64bit).

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py", line 13, in <module>
    os.add_dll_directory(extra_dll_dir)
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'
>>>
```